# Play scala passing List[Int] values from form to controller shows No URL path bind er found for type List[Int] and type mismatch error

Tags: list, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, scala-template

In my `Play scala project` I have multiple selection of `drop down` items.I have viewed my `scala.html` file successfully with multiple selection of values in `drop down`.

**What I need**

When submitting a form I need to pass multiple selected drop down `values(List[Int])` from `form` to `controller` for this I have used `employeeForm("languagesids").value` but It shows below error

```
[error]  found   : Option[String]
[error]  required: List[Int]
```

I have tried with `employeeForm("languagesids").get` but this too couldn't help.
and also its showing

```
  No URL path bind
    er found for type List[Int]
```

this error in routes file

**What I tried**

I tried with accessing a selected value list in `Controller` by below code

```
def registerEmployee = Action { implicit request =>  

        algorithmForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.employeeRegisterForm(formWithErrors,LanguageType.options)),
      employee=> {
          play.api.Logger.info("employee langauge list size :"+employee.languagesids.size)
```

It gives list size as 0 if we select items

**controller/Employees.scala**

```
     val employeeForm= Form(
        mapping(
          "employeeid" -> ignored(None:Option[Int]),
          "employeename" -> nonEmptyText,    
          "languagesids" -> ignored(None:Option[List[Int]])

        )(models.Employee.apply)(models.Employee.unapply)
      )

 def createEmployee = Action {  implicit request =>      
       Ok(html.employeeRegisterForm(employeeForm,LanguageType.options.options))
       }

     }
```

**models/Employee.scala**

```
  case class Employee(
      employeeid:  Option[Int] = None,
      employeename:String,  
      languagesids:Option[List[Int]] = None
        )
    case class LanguageType(
     languageid: Option[Int] = None,
  languagename: String
  )
    object Employee{


    }
object LanguageType{

   val simple = {
    get[Option[Int]]("language_type.LANG_ID") ~
    get[String]("language_type.LANG_NAME") map {      
      case languageid~languagename=> LanguageType(languageid,languagename)
    }
  }

  def options: Seq[(String,String)] = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
 SQL("select * from language_type")      
      foldLeft[Seq[(String, String)]](Nil) { (cs, c) => 
        c.languageid.fold(cs) { id => cs :+ (id.toString -> c.languagename) }
      }
  } 

}
```

**views/employeeRegisterForm.scala.html**

```
@(employeeForm: Form[Employee],languageTypes: Seq[(String, String)])


    @form(routes.Employee.registerEmployee(employeeForm("languagesids").value) {

        <fieldset>

            @inputText((employeeForm("algoname"), '_label -> "Employee Name", '_help -> "",'placeholder -> "Employee Name")
            @inputText(employeeForm("algodesc"), '_label -> "Employee Description", '_help -> "",'placeholder -> "Description")      


             @multiSelect(
    employeeForm("languagesids"),
    languageTypes,
    '_label -> "Select Tags" ,'_default -> "-- Choose Tag --"         
  )         

        </fieldset>

        <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Employee" > 

        </div>

    }

}
```

**routes**

```
   GET  /register/:languageList     controllers.Employees.registerEmployee(languageList:List[Int])
```

**views/multiSelect.scala.html**

```
@**
 * Generate an HTML multi-select.
 *
 * Example:
 * {{{
 * @select(field = myForm("categories"), options = options("A","B","C"))
 * }}}
 *
 * @param field The form field.
 * @param args Set of extra attributes.
 * @param handler The field constructor.
 *@

 @import helper._

@(field: play.api.data.Field, options: Seq[(String,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)

@values = @{ field.indexes.map { v => field("[" + v + "]").value } }

@input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    <select id="@id" name="@name" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs) multiple="multiple">
        @options.map { v =>
            <option value="@v._1" @{if(values.contains(Some(v._1))) "selected" else ""}>@v._2</option>
        }
    </select>
}
```

Comment: Can you please include content of `multiSelect.scala.html` in your question?

Comment: @bjfletcher I edited my question with `multiSelect.scala.html`

Comment: You're submitting languageIds in the form, so there's no need to include langaugeIds in the routes path pattern and as a param in the controller method. You can use "bindFromRequest" to get it out. Or is there a reason you need to do it the way you've given above? By the way, if you need to use List[Int] in your routes then where's your path binder for this?

Comment: I already added in my question that I have tried with `bindFromRequest` method.
`def registerEmployee = Action { implicit request =>  

        algorithmForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.employeeRegisterForm(formWithErrors,LanguageType.options)),
      employee=> {
          play.api.Logger.info("employee langauge list size :"+employee.languagesids.size)`

in this approach I have get `employee name` in result but didn't get `list values`

Comment: for this `bindFromRequest` my `routes` would be `GET  /register  controllers.Employees.registerEmployee`

and the `employeeRegisterForm.scala.html` would be `@form(routes.Employee.registerEmployee()
{
}`